# Finding a string of numbers within another string

Tags: c++, string, substring

So, I'm having a problem in C++.

I need to search for a string of five numbers that won't always be in the same spot in a string.

For example, sometimes the source string might be "sjdjfut93835sxx" and other times it may be "jj3333333335".

In the first string, I would need to exctract "93835". In the second string, I wouldn't extract anything since the string of numbers is over five characters.

I need to find strings of numbers that are 5 characters long and only numbers, no letters in-between.

What would the easiest way of doing this be? I'm having a lot of trouble with this and can't find an answer to it anywhere on Google or past StackOverflow questions

Thanks!

Comment: A simple nested loop and the [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit) function should suffice.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Or use [`std::find_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) (with `std::isdigit` as predicate) to get the start of the digit sequence, then use `std::find_if_not` to find the end. Use [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) to check the "distance" (i.e. length) between those positions.

Comment: If there were more than one such string in the larger string to be searched, what would you return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try splitting the task up into two steps.

First, use something like regular expressions to pull out all of the numeric strings (93835 and 3333333335 in your example).

Second, remove any results that aren't 5 characters long.

Comment: Um, regular expressions are perfectly capable of doing both steps in one: `(^|[^0-9])([0-9]{5,5})($|[^0-9])`.  Of course, not sure how easy finding a library will be in c++.

Comment: @ZacHowland darn that little C++11 on there...  I mean, I know it's 2014 and all, but for some reason things move slowly.

Comment: @ebyrob I haven't brushed up on my regex syntax in a while, but will that return any sequence of 5 numeric characters that are found?  ie. Example number two would return 33333 (and maybe more).

Comment: @JoshuaMagashazi It should.  `[0-9]{5,5}` will match any 5 numbers 0-9 consecutive.  However, I then wanted to rule out anything "extra" and also be able to use a regex group, `\2` I think, to return the match we're actually interested in (when a match occurs).

Comment: @ebyrob Also, the expression could simply be `\d{5}`.  If the OP wants to return all possible combinations of 5 consecutive numbers in the string, he could return a set of strings each containing 5 digits.

Comment: @ZacHowland See my comment in another answer.  My reading of the question was that if there were more than 5 digits e.g. `3333333335` *nothing* should be returned.  (no match)

Comment: @ebyrob That actually makes the expression easier.  It would simply be `.*\d.*`.  And any results that do not have exactly 5 digits are thrown out.

Comment: @ZacHowland I think you mean `\d+`.  But.  Then only step 1) would get done by the regex.  Why bring in a powerful (expensive) tool if you're not going to take advantage of it?

Comment: @ebyrob Oops, mistyped.  And the reason you would split it up is due to the ease of checking the length of a string vs the regex checking to make sure that it is exactly 5 characters and does not have "invalid" data before or after it (e.g. it isn't 5 digits surrounded by digits).  If the input was "abc123456def12345hij123456789", the regex result set would contain `123456`, `12345`, and `123456789`, and comparing the lengths would quickly get you `12345`.

Answer (score 1):

with `std::regex`

```
int extract(const string& str) {
  smatch result;
  regex r("\\d{5}");
  regex_search(str, result, r);
  return stoi(result.str());
}
```

this function(stoi) throws an exception if the number is not found.

Edit:: this function also matches string that contain more than 5 consecutive digits.
you can modify the regex to `(^|\\D)\\d{5}($|\\D)`, then remove the first non-digit(if there is one) before calling `stoi`.

Comment: Or modify the return value to return a `std::string` instead.  If the return value is empty, it was not found.  Otherwise, you can easily convert it using `std::stol`.

Comment: @ZacHowland ya, I usually use `boost::optional<int>` for this.

Comment: Wouldn't this exactly match exactly 5 numbers next to... other numbers?

Comment: @yngum That works as well.  I wish they hadn't cut the `optional<>` template from the proposed C++14 standard ...

Comment: `(?<!\d)\d{5}(?!\d)` would work. I'm unsure if the C++ regex engine supports negative lookahead/behind.

Answer (score 0):

That would be pretty simple to do with DFA (deterministic finite automaton) algorithms and pattern matching ones. Examples are [Boyer-Moore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) algorithm or [Knuth-Morris-Pratt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm)'s one. You can find thorough descriptions of them into any algorithm book.

Otherwise as Joshua noted you might use some ready regex libraries and have the searching and pattern matching work done by it.

Your specific problem might also be solved "manually" with a hand-crafted solution (if I understood it correctly) like the following:

- Scan the string one character at a time
- If you meet a number, start counting how many there are next
- If > 5, then drop it and reset the counter until you find another number

pretty easy and **O(N)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can create simple finite state machine with the states:

```
1) Waiting for digit
2) Have first digit, waiting for second digit
3) Have second digit, waiting for third digit
4) ...
5) ...
6) ...
7) Have fifth digit, waiting for letter or end of string
8) Finish. Return string.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
string text="sjdjfut93835sxx";

int digitCount=0;
string aux="";
for(int i=0; i<strlen(text); i++)
{

if(text[i]>=48 && text[i]<=57) // if is a digit
{
digitCount++;
aux+=text[i];
if(digitCount==5)
{
cout<<"I found it! "<<aux;
}

}
else
{
aux="";
digitCount=0;
}
}
```

Comment: `strlen` on a string, in a for loop condition  ? Not using iterators ? Comparing to `48` and `57` instead of `'0'` and `'9'` ?

Comment: I can't compare it with 48 and 57, because text[i] is a char, i have to compare to the ascii code.

Comment: Yes, you should. But you're doing: `if(text[i]>=48 && text[i]<=57) // if is a digit`

Comment: Yea, because if the character is in the interval [48;57] it means that is a digit.

Comment: I understood what you did but you'd better do something like `(text[i] >= '0' && text[i] <= '9')`... Or better `std::isdigit(text[i])`.

Comment: Is the same thing, it doesn't matters, using ascii code is good for understanding it.

Comment: I don't agree at all but I admit that's more a matter of taste. But my main concern was that you're using `strlen` on a `std::string`. You should at least fix this...